# 2 WAN роутер-балансировщик трафика и тунель

Tags: сеть

Ситуация:

роутер-балансировщик 2 WAN ports IN (MikroTik RB951G-2HnD), соответственно создано 2 интерфейса для работы с каждым провайдером, при этом имеем 2 статичных IP привязанных по существу к одному девайсу.
 При этом надо иметь *постоянной* поднятый `pppd` тунель для слива `VoIP` трафика через него для обеспечения работы внутри корпоративной телефонии в  разных сегментах (территориально) предприятия.

Вопрос-задача-проблема:
Если туннель прокинут через один из провайдеров (к примеру 1), то при "падении" этого провайдера  тунель также "упадет".

Внимание вопрос:
 Есть ли возможность автоматически заставить сам роутер, или как то программно определять падение туннеля/канала(через который прокинут туннель) и пересоздавать туннель через активный(оставшийся работать) интернет канал(провайдер 2)?

Спасибо, если поможете/подскажите что по существу.

Answer (score 0):

Нет данных как вы обрабатываете потерю канала. Если при падении одного из внешних каналов вы смените основной шлюз с одного провайдера на другого то ррр-клиент скорее всего тоже будет реконектиться через второй канал.

Comment: девайс автоматом меняет провайдера на доступный, в этом и фишка таковых от микротика. Основной момент именно в туннеле, интернет в даном контексте вторичен по важности решения задачи.

Comment: Я проверил в связке РС(mikrotik os 5.26, 2 isp, pptp-client) => Internet => hAPac (router os 6.34, pptp-srv). На РС подключено 2 разных провайдера, прописано 2 маршрута по-умолчанию с разным distance. При отключении активного линка (того у которого distance меньше) его маршрут 0.0.0.0/0 становится неактивным и автоматически весь трафик не имеющий отдельно описанных маршрутов идет через 2 провайдера по его маршруту 0.0.0.0/0 PPTP-client естественно тоже идет во второй канал, но так как hAP не ждет трафик c этого IP линк обрывается. Через минуту клиент поднимается заново автоматически.

Comment: Прямо интересно, почему рекомендация менять шлюз по умолчанию не является ответом? Вот у меня на одном из объектов это работает отлично...